# Override CopyToQuote in PMQuoteMaint

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to override the CopyToQuote method in PMQuoteMaint, but when I load the screen, I am getting an error saying the method with that signature is not found. I verified the method was public in PMQuoteMaint and my method signature matches. I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I am at a loss for what is not working. Here is my code:

```
    public delegate void CopyToQuoteDelegate(PMQuote currentquote, PMQuoteMaint.CopyQuoteFilter param);
    [PXOverride]
    public void CopyToQuote(PMQuote currentquote, PMQuoteMaint.CopyQuoteFilter param, CopyToQuoteDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //My Code here
        baseMethod(currentquote, param);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Project Quote screen (PM304500), you can extend/override the Action "Copy Quote".
The action returns an enumerator, and accepts PXAdapter as input parameter.
In your case, "CopyToQuote" method in the base graph **PMQuoteMaint**, is not marked as virtual, so you cannot override it.  If you want to change the base behavior, I recommend to override the Action, and add your custom logic

```
    public delegate IEnumerable CopyQuoteDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable CopyQuote(PXAdapter adapter, CopyQuoteDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        // add your custom logic here
        // to override the base logic           

        return adapter.Get();  //just returns the enumerator
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was under the assumption that Acumatica didn't need the method to be virtual using PXOverride and that it was doing something else under the covers. I'm not sure ovderriding CopyQuote will work for me, but I'll see what I can do. It's strange because that method is virtual in every other graph (OpportunityMaint and QuoteMaint), but not in this one... thanks again!